# Remove chapter number in Sectioning only for the chapter 0

Tags: sectioning

I'm using the following format for the sectioning:

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

Before starting the chapter 1, I start with an introduction that I use in it the sectioning, and I faced the following problem:

[image]

And here is my code snippet for this section:

```
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{\centering\Huge\bf\color{myblue}{Introduction}}\par
\vspace{1cm}
\section{Overview}
```

Can anyone help me please to get rid of this 0 from the sectioning only in the introduction part?

Comment: Use again `\section*{Overview}` instead of `\section{Overview}`. Simplest solution. Sectioning commands with "star" disable theyre numbering.

Comment: And also, it is better (even for simple cases) not to post code snippets, but to post stand-alone compilable MWE (with documentclass, package loadings, etc ...) that can be just copy-pasted for testing.

Comment: you could use `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\arabic{section}.\fi\arabic{subsection}}` but the reader may find it confusing, better to use `\section*` and not number, I think.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you i tried your command for the section and it works for me but i still have a problem for the subsection : \renewcommand\thesection{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\fi\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\arabic{section}.\fi\arabic{subsection}}  where the subsection is only numbered without being precede with the section number

Comment: you have not provided a test document or even a fragment showing any use of `\subsection`

Comment: the code in my comment above should be `\renewcommand\thesection{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\fi\arabic{section}.` I'd just copied your definition of subsection but there are no subsections here

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes i've used your command for both section and subsection in case the chapter number is >0 but what i'm asking you is how can i customize the subsection to be like the following format (section.subsection) in case the chapter number is 0????

Comment: just move the `\fi` to before the `\arabic{section}`  but really you should provide a test document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you so much it works now !!!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's clearer to use unnumbered sections in the front matter, but if you want to do this then:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\fi\arabic{section}}
% this one shouldn't be needed as it's the default
%\renewcommand\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
```